# Convert a PDF to greyscale on the command line in FLOSS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, pdf

I have a colour PDF file, and I'm going to print it out and then photocopy it in black and white. I'd like to know what it's like in B&W before photocopying it. Is it possible to 'greyscale' a PDF on the command line using free software? I'm using Ubuntu 9.10.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

ImageMagick can do this.

```
convert -colorspace GRAY color.pdf gray.pdf
```

via this [email](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-users/2006-June/006807.html)

Comment: That significantly reduces quality. @goyinux' solution is better.

Comment: Convert will actually rasterize the contents of the pdf. So unless the pdf already encapsulates only raster images (e.g. a scanned document), this approach is a big no-no.

Comment: Unless you use `-density 400 -quality 100` parameters - that works well

Comment: Really, is there anything ImageMagick _can't_ do? :)

Comment: `-density 400 -quality 100` creates HUGE files. +1 for @goyinux's solution.

Comment: The big files print great (only using  black toner) while the original and gs-converted file use all toners and create a vague mess on my printer.

Comment: What's the reason for `convert` to reduce the quality of rasterized images? I tried using the options `convert -density 300 -quality 100`, in order to prevent this behaviour of `convert`. But the quality of the output image is still much worse than the quality of the input image... so are there options for `convert`, that prevent the encapsulated images from quality loss, when converting `pdf`'-files encapsulating rasterized images?

Comment: Another problem with `convert ` is that OCRed pdf files lose the text layer. That is, one loses the OCR. While the method with `gs` keeps OCR.

Comment: ``convert -density 200 -colorspace GRAY``  worked like a charm for me

Comment: With proper `-density` it gives nice grayscale. In case you need black/white with clean background it is more suitable `-density 300 -threshold 75%`. It may be useful when you keep original scans in color and want to reprint it.

Answer (score 216):

Better:

```
gs \
 -sOutputFile=output.pdf \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
 -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray \
 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
 -dNOPAUSE \
 -dBATCH \
 input.pdf
```

Comment: Agreed, this gives much better results than convert, but sometimes it rotates the pdf which is a bit annoying!

Comment: Just realised you can disable that with `-dAutoRotatePages=/None`

Comment: I just ran this command on a 58MB PDF that was already greyscale (came from a scanner) and the resulting output was 10MB and looked exactly the same. Nice!

Comment: Works well on Windows, too! Just remove the `\\` and put everything on the same line.

Comment: In fact, this fails with this error `GPL Ghostscript 9.10: 
Unable to convert color space to Gray, reverting strategy to LeaveColorUnchanged.`

Comment: Works great. But output image size is almost 3x for my file. I have a complicated vector-drawing colorful file with 3.5 MB size that became 10 MB!

Comment: This is really fantastic. Perfect for scanned documents for subsequent print.

Comment: Some people complains that the size of the *grayscale* image is not lower than the *original*. If, besides turning the image grayscale, you want to compress it, add the following option `-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook` . Instead of `/ebook` you can also use `/screen` for a more radical compression (i.e. lower quality). Enjoy it!

Comment: This may be better than the imagemagick convert, but it does *not* render losslessly.  in particular, fonts are lost.  text is now rendered, probably as graphics primitives, not as fonts.   `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` is really loq quality, which the original file may not have been.

Answer (score 16):

Here’s a little script which in addition to the grayscale conversion can concatenate multiple input files.
To use the script, put the following lines in a file, e.g. "convert2gray.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
gs -sOutputFile=converted.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray -dCompatibiltyLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH $@
```

and make it executable

```
chmod +x convert2gray.sh
```

Then

```
./convert2gray.sh input1.pdf input2.pdf … lastinput.pdf
```

will produce a single PDF "converted.pdf", which contains all pages from the input files converted to grayscale.

I had to print out mutliple files all in grayscale and found this the easiest way, since you can print out everything after inpection with one command.

Comment: FWIW, pdftk can concatenate PDFs, too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am keeping signed document scans in color, but need reprint it without gray noice. For this case works well

```
convert -density 300 -threshold 75% input.pdf output.pdf
```

(based on [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84711/411221))

Range between 50%-75% works fine in circumstances when you have color scan PDF (text as image) with original resolution 300dpi.

In case of text saved as PDF (not image) you will get huge increasing of output file size.