# Convert a colored PDF into a white/black

Tags: linux, pdf

On Debian Sid, I have a PDF with a blue background and yellow font. I've searched a lot on Super User but i haven't found anything useful for me.

I have tried to convert the PDF into a grayscale one with:

```
gs -o grayscale.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 colored.pdf
```

The problem is that I obtain a PDF whit white fonts and dark grey background so I cannot print it.

After that I tried:

```
convert -density 96x96 gs2.pdf -density 96x96 -negate -compress zip inv.pdf
```

I got a PDF with black fonts (and this is okay) and grey background (and this is not okay).

What can I do to obtain a PDF with white background and black fonts?

Comment: If there is not much graphics in there, you can create a new pdf with all text.

Comment: @Lamb how can i do it??

Comment: Maybe you can make Ghostscript output a purely black-and-white PDF, rather than a grayscale one? Then you could invert that one.

Comment: i have thought to this but i have no idea on how to do it xD @MichaelKjörling

Comment: look at this question as well http://superuser.com/questions/200378/converting-a-pdf-to-black-white-with-ghostscript

Answer (score 10):

## GENERAL WARNING!!! work on a COPY of your FILE!!!

(so you can have  second chance if you made mistakes)

***vector*** pdf background (meaning not **raster image**) in pdf files can be
easily changed in a couple of steps (see also my stackoverflow answer that
now I'll extend and improve

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856521/change-background-color-of-pdf10869208#10869208)

---

- **PRELIMINAR CHECK**:

---

open your pdf file with an editor able to show the internal pdf structure,
like

**notepad++**

- http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.1.8.html
  (portable version in a zip file works well with wine in Linux or you can use **vim** as well)

and verify if you can see code snippets like

> **1.000 1.000 0.000 rg** (it means *yellow*)
>
> **0.000 0.000 1.000 rg** (it means **blue** *if your **blue** is the **pure blue** having RGB triplet 0, 0, 255, otherwise read the rest of answer to identify the right triplet into pdf code*)

and so on...

(code snippet can change, for instance, in pdf produced by openoffice
internal pdf exporting feature, the same code snippepts are in this forms:

```
0 0 0 rg (it means *black*)
1 1 1 rg (it means *white*)
```

and so on...

if you are able to see these code snippets, then you can start to change
values, otherwise, you need to decompress text streams

you can perform this task with

**pdftk**

http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/

```
pdftk file.pdf output uncompressed.pdf uncompress
```

and recompress after finished changes

```
pdftk uncompressed.pdf output recompressed.pdf compress
```

now, if you see these code snippets, you can change values

## STEP 1 (for pdf editing) -

the first thing you need is to find the right equivalence between RGB
color values of text and background and the internal pdf represerntation
of same colors

you can use a free color pickers like these

to identify the rgb values of text and background colors

- http://freecode.com/projects/grabc
- http://gcolor2.sourceforge.net/

once you have these values, you need to convert into special internal pdf
representation

to do this take i mind this proportion:

1:255=x:color you selected

for instance: let say you have this RGB triplet for background: 30,144,255

[image: rgb triplet blue]

to know correspondent values in pdf in order to insert in code snippet to
change pdf background color, you do: (you can use http://www.wolframalpha.com/ to compute with precision)

```
1:255=x:30 = 30/255 = 0.117 (approximated to first three decimals)

1:255=x:144 = 144/255 = 0.564 (approximated to first three decimals)

1:255=x:255 = 255/255 = 1
```

so, the whole triplet in pdf, corresponding to **RGB 30,144,255**, will be:

**0.117 0.564 1.000**

---

### # STEP 2 (for pdf editing)

we look for **0.117 0.564 1.000** in pdf file with notepad++ (***wrap around***
and ***match one word only*** needed to be checked) and we found the internal
pdf representation of background and we can change from azure to, let say,
white

**1.000 1.000 1.000**

or

**1 1 1**

but, since you wrote about *blue background* , to be more precise, I created a sample pdf with *blue background* (**pure blue** 0,0,255 RGB - if youe **blue** had different tonality modify as needed my tips) and *yellow text*

- http://ge.tt/3mFIRfP

since we know that  0.000 0.000 1.000 rg means *blue*, we look for this
and we can change from 0.000 0.000 1.000 rg, to 1.000 1.000 1.000 rg
(white) BUT...

at same time, you also change the text from yellow to black

looking for
**1.000 1.000 0.000** (yellow text) and change to black **0.000 0.000 0.000**

and we have now a vector pdf with **black** text and **white** background

please, remember to

> 1. - compress again this pdf you mmodified if you uncompressed with
>        pdftk
> 2. - repair

```
pdftk file.pdf output fixed.pdf
```

there is another way, starting from postscript, to perform the same task, but since you already have the **pdf file**, converting to postscript to perform the similar task would be superfluous step

give a feedback, please, and feel free to ask more

Comment: I'm glad to have been a bit useful :-)

Comment: Yes, it was helpful, after unsuccessfully trying all these non-working ghostscript or ImageMagick suggestions on the web!