# How to view PDF with changed background color?

Tags: pdf

I have some PDF and want to have light gray background when viewing them, but i don't need to permanently change its background.

What's the easiest way to do that?  I normally view it using Preview on Mac OS X, but i don't have to use it.

Comment: My hunch is that this will be very difficult without changing the text as well

Comment: Slightly changing the style of the text is OK.  My goal is less contrast between background and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to modify the source of this fork of [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/), which is [ParaPDF](https://github.com/paradigm/paraPDF):

> paraPDF is a fork of MuPDF.  It's simply intended to add a few
> features muPDF was missing which I was interested in, if I can't get
> them to upstream, and add some additional keybindings to make it feel
> more like home (home being vim).
>
> Specifically, here's the changes I'm workig on:
>
> - Reload the PDF when receiving a SIGHUP.  This can be useful, for example,    when working with LaTeX or something else that outputs
>   PDFs.
> - **Create a keybinding to invert the colors**.  This can be useful if one uses a    dark color scheme.  It would be preferable to refrain
>   from inverting images,    but that's likely to much work for the
>   effort (and my capabilities).
> - Added a flag to start with colors inverted.
> - Add some bindings to make muPDF feel a bit more like vim.  Most notably,    ctrl-e, ctrl-y, ctrl-f, ctrl-b, and gg.
>
> muPDF's original README follows (with my addition to the copyright):

---

Otherwise, you can convert the white background of your PDF to whatever color you want, following [the procedure I described here](https://superuser.com/questions/488813/convert-a-colored-pdf-into-a-white-black/488866#488866). Work on a copy of PDF and use this resulting PDF when you want read it with a gray background. This only works for PDFs with a vector background.

In your case, you change to gray, but the logic is the same for any other color you want to set.

Answer (score 1):

In Adobe Acrobat Reader, you can set a custom background color as part of the accessibility options, provided that there is no background image.

#### Steps

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> or go to **Edit → Preferences**.
2. Under **Categories**, select **Accessibility**.
3. Check **Replace Document Colors** and **Custom Color**.
4. Set **Page Background** to the desired color.
5. Click **OK**.

The instructions are for Acrobat Reader 9. Other versions should be similar.