# How to change color (and other details) of pdfs?

Tags: pdf

I have been sent a pdf which I'm supposed to print. The problem is, the text in the pdf is black and I want it in blue, but I have no idea how I can change this. How can you change the color of a pdf?

Comment: see my answer

http://superuser.com/questions/488813/convert-a-colored-pdf-into-a-white-black/488866#488866

Comment: Here's an online tool that changes pdf colors: https://supertool.org/automatically-add-color-to-pdfs-to-print-without-black-ink/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change setting in Adobe Acrobat Reader:

## I error ... it view only, but not print ... wait plz!

[image: Change setting in Adobe Acrobat Reader]

[image]

[image]

[image]