# Convert PDF image into true grayscale?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Following the answers to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/104656/convert-a-pdf-to-greyscale-on-the-command-line-in-floss) I get the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gs \
 -sOutputFile=/tmp/output.pdf \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
 -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=Gray \
 -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray \
 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
 -dNOPAUSE \
 -dBATCH \
  $1

mv /tmp/output.pdf $1
```

However, running `identify -verbose file.pdf | grep Colorspace` afterwards shows `Colorspace: sRGB`.

I want to make these true grayscale PDFs, and have the Colorspace be set to gray. I have one PDF that reports gray, but I don't know how to make ghostscript convert the other ones to be like it.