# Error in converting color pdf into grayscale pdf in Linux - 'File has errors...'

Tags: pdf, conversion, imagemagick, grayscale

I have been trying to convert a color pdf to a grayscale pdf prior to printing to avoid the color printing costs. I am using Debian and ImageMagick commands:

`convert -monochrome swp574.pdf output2.pdf`

`convert -colorspace GRAY swp574.pdf swp574GRAY.pdf`

`pdf2ps swp574.pdf output2.pdf`

and I get this response on the terminal each time.

```
File has circular references in resource dictionaries.
**** File has circular references in resource dictionaries.

**** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
**** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
**** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
**** specification.
```

How can I get over this problem?

Comment: Please consult this - http://superuser.com/questions/104656/convert-a-pdf-to-greyscale-on-the-command-line-in-floss

Comment: @hkdtam, i did and used those commands, but there is a problem with the pdf internals for the correctness of the Adobe pdf formatting

Comment: thanks for your feedback, did you mean the ghostscript solution in the link cause problems?

Comment: @hkdtam, those commands in the question did not work and neither did the gs commands work. Something in the pdf caused the problem.

Comment: It seems that you are dealing with some very special stuff here.  If it is not a sensitive document you may try your luck at [here](http://greyscalepdf.com/)

Comment: @hkdtam, tried it without any success...

Comment: Oh I see, actually the file is that broken I guess you may just save your time by reprinting it on Windows with grayscale using a PDF printer driver like pdfcreator. Just have a look on the last section of this [link](https://wiki.carleton.edu/display/itskb/PDFCreator)